# Using a JS Class with static properties not working in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a class with a static property in a seperate file in a Vue2 App:

```
export class TestUnit {
    static testVar = "test";
}
```

When I try to import the class

```
import { TestUnit } from "../../poco/classes/TestUnit";
```

I get the "Failed to compile" - Error with the following message:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| export class TestUnit {
>     static testVar = "test";
```

I didn't find a solution searching after the error message. Do you have an idea what the problem is?

Update: Static methods in the TestUnit class are working: `static test() { return "test" };` That confuses me.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It works for me.

Comment: Ok then the problem is my local machine I guess...

Comment: Have you added additional configuration in your vue.config.js? Are you using Babel for compiling? it looks like a problem in your bundler/compiler

Comment: @Kakiz Where can I see if I am using Babel for compiling in my Vue App (sorry for the question i'm a beginner)? My vue.config.js looks like this:  module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your node version,

- the static class fields are supported in version 12.4.0 and above.
- the static methods are supported since 5.12

you can check node's supported features here: https://node.green

Comment: I am using node v16.17.0